# Python requests returns “cannot connect to proxy & error 10061”

Tags: python, tcp, connection, python-requests

I have developed a desktop client using PyQt4, it connect to my web service by [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/) lib. You know, [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/) maybe one of the most useful http client, I think it should be no problem. My desktop client works all right until something strange happened.

I use the following code to send request to my server.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers = self.getHeaders(), timeout=600, proxies = {}, verify = False)
```

where header only includes auth token.

```
 def getHeaders(self, additional = None):
    headers = {
               'Auth-Token' : HttpBasicClient.UserAuthToken,
               }
    if additional is not None:
        headers.update(additional)
    return headers
```

I cannot connect to my web service, all the http request pop the same error "'Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10061, '')". For example:

> GET Url: http://  api.fangcloud.com/api/v1/user/timestamp
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.fangcloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/user/timestamp (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10061, '')))

this API does nothing but return the timestamp of my server. When I copy the url into Chrome in same machine with same environment, it returns correct response. However, my desktop client can only returns error. Is it anything wrong with requests lib?

I googled this problem of connection error 10061 ("No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"). This maybe caused by TCP connect rejection of web server.

> The client sends a SYN packet to the server targeting the port (80 for HTTP). A server that is running a service on port 80 will respond with a SYN ACK, but if it is not, it will respond with a RST ACK. Your client reaches the server, but not the intended service. This is one way a server could “actively refuse” a connection attempt.

But why? My client works all right before and Chrome still works. I use no proxy on my machine. Is there anything I miss?

Comment: share the python code

Comment: mainly 10061 comes from the OS (not Python) - but your mention of api working fine from browser is something to look into. did you test it using from the same system ? and same request params ?

Comment: Yep, I use Postman (the http client plugin of Chrome), fill the same params, it works all right too. Is this because OS security strategy?

Comment: are you using any proxy ? if not try it without the empty proxies = {} param, and also try it using urlib2 - to get to the issue

Answer (score 0):

I notice there is a white space in URL, is that correct?
I tested in my ipython with requests.. that the response was:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1472760770,
   "success": true
}
```

For HTTP and HTTPS.